# sed in bash: '-n' as input is treated differently?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed, command-line-arguments

I'm struggling with a problem with `sed` in bash which occurs both on macOS and Ubuntu. During a long debugging session I pinpointed it down to this minimal example:

`echo "abcde" | sed 's/.*/x/'`
which results in:

> x

Which makes sense as the regex in `sed` replaces any input with `x`.

Similarly:

`echo "" | sed 's/.*/x/'`

> x

`echo "-a" | sed 's/.*/x/'`

> x

Et cetera. However:

`echo "-n" | sed 's/.*/x/'`

> 

Note that the output is now *empty*.

What's going on? Why is `"-n"` as input to `sed` treated differently than any other (or no) input?

Comment: **It's the output from `echo` not the input to `sed`.** Run `echo "-n"` by itself and you'll see it produces no output -- on your system(s); this isn't the same for _all_ echo utilities.

Comment: If you want to print something that starts with `-` or contains backslash (or are tempted to pass options like `-n` or `-e` to `echo`), use `printf` instead of `echo`. It's more complicated to use properly -- the first argument is a format string that tells it how to print the rest of the arguments -- but much more controllable and predictable. In this case, you'd use `printf '%s\n' "thing you want to print"`. See ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `echo`, not `sed`.

You can examine the output with, for example, `hexdump -cx`.

```
echo a | hexdump -cx
0000000   a  \n                                                        
0000000    0a61                                                        
0000002
```

For the `echo a`, you'll get the output `a` and a new-line `\n` or 0x0a.

```
echo "" | hexdump -cx
0000000  \n                                                            
0000000    000a                                                        
0000001
```

Now, because the string is empty, you get only a new-line.

```
echo "-n" | hexdump -cx
```

`-n` means for `echo` do not output the trailing newline. So, now you have no string to echo and no new-line appended. So nothing at all.

`echo` has no option `-a`, so the `-a` is interpreted as a string to echo and not as an option.

So, with `$` as prompt:

```
$ echo -n -a  | sed 's/.*/x/'
x$ echo  -a  | sed 's/.*/x/'
x
```

Comment: I guess depending on the implementation of `sed` `echo -n -a  | sed 's/.*/x/'` may print nothing. `sed` is obliged to work with text files, it may or may not work with files that are not text files. `echo -n -a` prints an incomplete line, the output is not a [text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446237/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This works at least for the Ubuntu-version. I don't have macOS, so I can't test there.